# how to prepare for segue an index for a value in a double array

Tags: ios, swift, segue

So I have this code in my first controller.

```
var countries = ["American", "Asian", "Italian"]
var items = [["Mcdonalds", "BurgerKing", "Big Boy"], ["PFChangs", "China One Buffet"], ["Pizza House", "Pizza Hit", "Olive Garden", "Maggianos"]]

 if (segue.identifier == "segueone")
{
    let cellIndexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)
    if  let unwrappedCellindexPath = cellIndexPath
    {
        var nextVC = (segue.destinationViewController as TableTwo)
        nextVC.items = items[unwrappedCellindexPath.row]
    }
}
}
```

and on the second table controller I have

```
var items: [String]?
```

I am looking to further process. I want to segue over one specific value in my double array to a third controller.  I understand that my code would not be not be much different, but am unsure how to go about sending over a specific index from my double array in my second controller to a third controller?

Comment: I essentially copied the segue code from the first controller for the second.  and added the var items: [String]?

Comment: You think Pizza Hut is Italian? Oooh boy.

Comment: Just as an example, ha.

Comment: In what controller is the decision made as to which string within one of the inner arrays you want to send to the third controller? You're sending one of the internal arrays to the second controller; does the user make the choice there, which of the restaurants in the list gets sent to the third controller?

Comment: that information is in the second segue.  The first controller (table) displays the the values in my countries array.  The second controller displays the specific array dependent upon the index path selection in the first controller.  For the third controller, I want to display only one specific instance/index dependent upon the index path selected in the second controller.

Comment: So, I don't  understand your problem then. The second controller's items property is a simple array; you just pass items[indexPath.row], based on the users selection.

Comment: I have a general understanding of the logic, but my code is the confusion.  I can see your point though, I am already in the nested array and just need to pass along the right index (of that array) to pass along my item.  But overall, does that mean I no loner require the "let cell path = ..." and "it let" statement?

Comment: You don't really need the "if let" construction in either controller. cellIndexPath would only be nil  if you forgot to hook up your IBOutlet (so self.tableView would be nil). In that case, you should let the app crash, so you know you forgot to do that.

Comment: so with that in mind, my code in the second controller would look like     "Let cellindexpath = self.tableView!.indexpath for cell(sender as UItableCell) and simply "nextVC.items[cellindexpath.row]"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I can't seem to get it working fully.  Do you mind taking a look?  I'm having problems with a subscript, which i am unaware of.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yiqrymrrtlda1a5/AACzRtM4RLy6dT5Ksf3JRYeJa?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to pass the index or the item?
To pass the item you would write

```
nextVC.item = items[unwrappedCellindexPath.row][index2]
```

Comment: Aren't index and the item synonymous?

Comment: no, the index is just the position in the array, an integer

Comment: Ahh, makes sense.  In my case then, I am looking to send a specific item within one of the specific arrays based upon index position.

Comment: yes, then you would use the double subscript notation, see above. Instead of an Array you would declare a variable 
    var item:String?
on the third controller

Comment: how would i implement this double subscript notation in my code?

Comment: ah ok, you pass the double array to your second controller and want to pass an item to the third? In that case you only have to unwrap the optional items array: thirdVC.item = items![unwrappedCellindexPath.row]

Comment: I know this was two days ago, but how would i go about setting up my item property in my third view controller?

Comment: simply var item:String?